# How to change type of an object instance after-the-fact

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I want to know how to convert/extend a pre-existing object instance of a given type (say, type 'Widget') to a new type (say, 'WidgetPlus'), so that the instance inherits all methods and variables of the original and the new.

So, if I have **widget_1**, **widget_2** and **widget_3**, all of which were instantiated as **new Widget()**, what is the best way to extend these instances to my new **WidgetPlus** class?

Thanks in advance,

Andy

Comment: Shouldn't you just change prototype of these objects? Just like `widget_1.prototype = WidgetPlus`

Comment: @justanothercoder: No, that cannot work

Comment: Why didn't you use `new WidgetPlus` in the first case? How do you determine which one you need, and when does that change? What is the difference between the two types? Is `WidgetPlus` a subclass of `Widget`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you *really* want to achieve.

```
var Widget = function(){
    this.name = 'Widget';
    this.a = 'a';
};
Widget.prototype.foo = function(){ return 'foo'; };

var WidgetPlus = function(){
    this.name = 'WidgetPlus';
    this.b = 'b';
};
WidgetPlus.prototype = new Widget(); // XXX: assumption
WidgetPlus.prototype.bar = function(){ return 'bar'; };

// Ignores prototype chain
var copy = function(dest, src){
    Object.keys(src).forEach(function(key){
        dest[key] = src[key];
    });
};
```

Overwrite widget_1 stuff with WidgetPlus.prototype stuff:

```
var widget_1 = new Widget();
copy(widget_1, WidgetPlus.prototype);
widget_1; // Widget {name: "Widget", a: "a", bar: function, foo: function}
```

Plus copy initializations:

```
copy(widget_1, new WidgetPlus());
widget_1; // Widget {name: "WidgetPlus", a: "a", bar: function, b: "b", foo: function}
```

Or overwrite new WidgetPlus() stuff with widget_1 stuff

```
var widget_1 = new Widget();
var old_widget_1 = widget_1;
widget_1 = new WidgetPlus();
copy(widget_1, old_widget_1);
widget_1; // WidgetPlus {name: "Widget", b: "b", a: "a", bar: function, foo: function}
```

Or maybe WidgetPlus doesn't really share a prototype chain
with Widget, and they have totally different functions; and
you want those too:

```
copy(widget_1, Widget.prototype);
```

Etc.